# Unable to use any 3rd party module with AWS Lambdas

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on a lambda that makes use of modules (async, request, etc)

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error 
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) 
at Module.require (module.js:364:17) 
at require (module.js:380:17) 
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:63) 
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) 
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Sample code:

```
var 
  AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
  util = require('util'),
  request = require('request');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   console.log('test');
   context.done();
};
```

It works fine (prints test) as long as no 3rd party modules (besides aws-sdk) are required. As soon as I just add a line such as:

```
require('request') // or async, config and so on
```

It fails with the above error. I have tried calling these modules directly as well by specifying the full path with no luck. It's like its looking at the wrong directory when calling `require`.

Dumping `process.env` in the console yields:

```
PATH: '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin',
LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT: '/var/task',
LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR: '/var/runtime',
AWS_REGION: 'us-west-2',
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-west-2',
AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME: '/aws/lambda/Thumbnailer',
AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME: '2015/12/10/[$LATEST]3f8ef236195448c88f206634bde6301b',
AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME: 'Thumbnailer',
AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE: '512',
AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION: '$LATEST',
NODE_PATH: '/var/runtime:/var/task:/var/runtime/node_modules',
```

Here's the [module](https://github.com/trinketapp/aws-lambda-create-thumbnail) I was working off - evidently this used to work at some point but does not for me.

Ideas? I feel that I am missing some configuration unique to lambdas here.

Comment: Can you describe your lambda deployment package?

Comment: @James - I zip the files (not the folder). Lambda seems to run fine, just cannot use that module.

Comment: Well - I should say it doesn't throw errors but nothing happens since its just the callback so perhaps other issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

omg that was painful... Turns out that OSX makes the `node_modules` folder readable only by the user and AWS cannot read it. Make the `node_modules` folder and content readable by world and it works. I am not sure if all OSX setups react the same. I am using `nvm` which may be the culprit.

**Update**. I used to set all files to `0666` but ran into issues with executables. Here's a little script that will address things properly. It will set all files to `0666` unless executables or a directory in which case `0777`. Run this from within the project folder (do be careful of the implications of not doing so!):

Here's a script from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41248905/856498) I posted:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . \
 '(' -perm -0700 -exec chmod 0777 '{}' + ')' -o \
 '(' -perm -0600 -exec chmod 0666 '{}' + ')'
```

Comment: I just experienced this problem but permissions were already world-readable. Any other ideas on cause or fix?

Comment: @ken see the comment by James - make sure you don't zip a folder but individual files.

Comment: I was just looking at the node-lambda code and it appears that it iterates through each file in the code directory and puts each into a single zip. Actually for non-windows it shells out to native zipping but same outcome. There doesn't seem to be a config option but actually I'd have thought this is the correct behaviour. Isn't it?

Comment: Hmm I've not used node-lambda yet. I just osx zip it and upload. The other thing that comes to mind is making sure your setup on AWS panel specifies the same entry point. I assume your code does have an index.js and your aws panel reflects that (I would assume if you have the same error as I did that its correct on the amazon side)

Comment: yeah I am working with a micro-service that _was_ deploying correctly but then I split the single JS file into a small number of submodules which are "required" in. Not sure if it was that or something else but for whatever reason it can't import my entrypoint file: `Unable to import module 'dist/transporter'`

Comment: How did you change the permissions? I'm facing the same problem, but changing the permissions using chmod isn't fixing the issue.

Comment: @Parth - I did use `chmod` - I made the node_modules folder as well as its recursive content all word readable.

Comment: Actually, my problem was that I was zipping the directory that contained index.js and node_modules, not the contents of the directory. Got it working finally! Thanks.