# chmod - replicate user permissions to group/world

Tags: bash, chmod

I have a need to make some folders/files (recursive) have the same permissions as that of the user. So:

- 0755 -> 0777
- 0644 -> 0666

How can I do so? Perhaps a little secret command I do know of?

If there is no easy way then perhaps I would need to create a loop and test/assign. Ultimately I only need to deal with 3 types:

Folders should be 777, most files 666, executables 777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` can do the work of finding files with a given permission set and  running the smallest possible number of `chmod` invocations necessary to cover them.

```
find . \
  '(' -perm -0700 -exec chmod 0777 '{}' + ')' -o \
  '(' -perm -0600 -exec chmod 0666 '{}' + ')'
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no command that does for you.  You do need a little loop:

```
for file in $(find . -print)
do
  if [ -d $file -o -x $file ]; then
    chmod 777 $file
  else
    chmod 666 $file
  fi
done
```

Comment: This is very, very buggy. Look at what happens with filenames with whitespace or wildcards. Also, run it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the quoting issues.

Comment: ...and as for the general practice of `for file in $(find . -print)`, see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: ...if you want to be able to safely and correctly handle arbitrary filenames from `find` in your shell scripts, you either need to use an `-exec` action to pass them to your script on argv, or `-print0` to generate a NUL-delimited stream. Search for `-print0` in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an example of the latter, or the "Complex Actions" section of [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for discussion of both.

Comment: Also, `-o` in `[ ]` is deprecated. See [the POSIX standard for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), and note the `[OB]` ("obsolescent") notation by the specification of `-a` and `-o`.