# Image resizing fails on AWS Lambda with nodejs package

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am trying to resize images on AWS following this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/).

After creating a Lambda Function for resize using [this code](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-resizing/raw/master/dist/function.zip), I hit the 'Test' button but I keep getting this error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}

START RequestId: 9e17d7d0-8fd8-11e7-a461-4f1c735f787e Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
END RequestId: 9e17d7d0-8fd8-11e7-a461-4f1c735f787e
REPORT RequestId: 9e17d7d0-8fd8-11e7-a461-4f1c735f787e  Duration: 1.83 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 1536 MB    Max Memory Used: 20 MB
```

I found a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208502/unable-to-use-any-3rd-party-module-with-aws-lambdas) which suggested something wrong with the nodejs code especially as the Test on the Lambda function is throwing those errors. I unzipped the folder and ran npm install after removing the node_packages folder following this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html) and made the node_modules folder world readable as well.

I then archived the directory and re-upoloaded it to the Lambda Function and ran Test but still getting the same error.

I am not sure what else could I do or where I am going wrong here?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that there is not an `index.js` file in the **root** of your zip file.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I unzipped the folder I uploaded and it does have index.js in it. This is the zip file I used. https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-resizing/raw/master/dist/function.zip